# Building a LinkedList from structs

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm trying to build a `Linkedlist` from an `array` of `structs` like this:

```
node * current = NULL, *list= NULL;

current = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));

current->employee.EMP_ID = ed[0].EMP_ID;
strcpy(current->employee.name, ed[0].name);
current->employee.dept = ed[0].dept;
current->employee.rank = ed[0].rank;
current->employee.salary = ed[0].salary;
current->next = NULL;

list = current;

current = current->next;

for (int i = 1; i < 2; i++){

    node *current = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));

    current->employee.EMP_ID = ed[i].EMP_ID;
    strcpy(current->employee.name, ed[i].name);
    current->employee.dept = ed[i].dept;
    current->employee.rank = ed[i].rank;
    current->employee.salary = ed[i].salary;
    current->next = NULL;

    list->next = current;

    current = current->next;
}
```

However, it's only storing the last value from the `struct`. What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
node * current = NULL, *list= NULL;

current = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));

current->employee = ed[0];
current->next = NULL;

list = current;

for (int i = 1; i < 2; i++){

    node *np = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));

    np->employee = ed[i];
    np->next = NULL;

    current = current->next = np;
}
```